# Unable to parse time in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

Let's say I have the following string:

`timeUTC = "14:28"`

And I would like to convert the above string to UTC+2.

So `timeUTCp2 = "16:28"`.

How can I do that using Python3? Is the quickest way to do this algebraically or using a dependency?

Comment: Are timezones a concern or do you just need to add two hours and get a string back?

Comment: Algebraically might not be best for such a calculation,  `adding 2 and % 24` might result in some weird times if the input was, for example `22:28` (which would result in `24:28`). For dates and times, I'd usually just recommend using a library, its almost never worth trying to do it yourself, unless speed is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 2 hours to UTC like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

time_str = "14:28"
time = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%H:%M")
utc = timezone('UTC').localize(time)

utcp2 = utc + timedelta(hours=2)
'{:%H:%M}'.format(utcp2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, that I can think of:

FIRST, if you want to just add two hours to the string time (that doesn't appear to have a timezone attached to it):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
dt = datetime.strptime("14:28", "%H:%M") + timedelta(hours=2)
```

SECOND, you could convert from whatever timezone the input string is from to UTC then add two hours. I don't know where that time string is coming from so I didn't construct an example of that.